# Join multiple columns - with single query

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am looking to join two table. One table has an id and other table has id and its corresponding value. I am using 4 joins to get value for 4 columns. COST of the query is too high. Is there a way to reduce the COST ?

sample code.

```
select b.empname, c.deptname, d.supervisorname 
from idtable A, lookuptable B,lookuptable C,lookuptable D
where b.lookuptable =a.empid  
and c.lookuptable=a.empdeptid 
and d.lookuptable = a.empsupervisorid;
```

Comment: share sample table and your tried querry

Comment: No table structure, no sample data, no expected output, no code...

Comment: Others have already mentioned that without the actual query and some sample data this is impossible to answer. But: how do you know the COST is "too high"? What would be an acceptable value? On which grounds do you decide the correct value for COST? How long does the query really take? How fast do you need it to be?

Comment: Due do confidentiality issues I am  not able to share the relevant data.

Comment: May be indexing the tables or creating a view or a function... In fact we don't know anything about your data model

Comment: That's a weird database design. So rather than having an `employee` table, a `department` table, and a `supervisor` table, you have a `something` table (that you call `lookuptable`)? Change this if possible.

Comment: avoid old comma-separated join use explicit join method

Comment: `Due do confidentiality issues I am not able to share the relevant data`. Provide some **sample** data and expected result for **that sample data**.

Answer (score 0):

Try yo use hints. If the lookuptable table is not too big, you could try

```
 /*+ CACHE(lookuptable)*/
```

Or, you can use:

```
/*+ USE_HASH(idtable lookuptable)*/
```